# How to get source web address of the copied text in clipboard?

Tags: clipboard

I am using OneNote in Windows in VirtualBox. When we copy text in web browser of Windows, and paste it in OneNote, it also pastes the web address of site from which the text was copied.

when I copy text from Firefox[any other browser] in ubuntu and paste it in onenote[online or in windows VM], the source web address is not present.

Is there any work around this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the "Clip to OneNote" addon for Firefox?

Comment: @Jos it is not available for Firefox on Ubuntu. The addon page says, "Not available for your platform"

Comment: It does not work on Linux because on windows the copied clipboard content has sourceURL while on linux it does not have this. If you use FreeClipboardViewer program you will see these fields `startfragment endfragment sourceurl`